# Intel MKL Error: Parameter 9 was incorrect on entry to cblas_zgemm (C# Linux)

Tags: c#, linux, cross-platform, dllimport, intel-mkl

I've build a [custom MKL library (2019 Update 2) for Windows](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-windows-developer-guide-using-the-custom-dynamic-link-library-builder-in-the-command-line-mode) (10)  and [Linux](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-linux-developer-guide-using-the-custom-shared-object-builder) (Ubuntu 18.04) using the following commands:

```
nmake libintel64 MKLROOT="C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries\windows\mkl" name=win\intel64\custom_mkl interface="lp64"
```

and

```
make libintel64 MKLROOT="opt/intel/mkl" name=linux/intel64/custom_mkl interface=lp64
```

I'm using `DllImport` from C# to call `cblas_zgemm`

```
[DllImport(DLLName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = false)]
internal static extern void cblas_zgemm(
    int Order, int TransA, int TransB, int M, int N, int K,
    ComplexDouble alpha, [In] ComplexDouble[,] A, int lda, [In] ComplexDouble[,] B, int ldb,
    ComplexDouble beta, [In, Out] ComplexDouble[,] C, int ldc);
```

see https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-cblas-gemm

where `ComplexDouble` is defined as:

```
public struct ComplexDouble
{
    public double real;
    public double imag;

    public static implicit operator ComplexDouble(double d)
    {
        return new ComplexDouble() { real = d };
    }
}
```

I've defined the following static method for the matrix multiplication:

```
public static ComplexDouble[,] Dot(ComplexDouble[,] a, ComplexDouble[,] b)
{
    int n1 = a.GetLength(0);
    int n2 = a.GetLength(1);
    int n3 = b.GetLength(0);
    int n4 = b.GetLength(1);
    if (n2 != n3) throw new System.Exception("Inner matrix dimensions must agree");
    int Order = 101; // row-major arrays
    int TransA = 111; // trans='N'
    int TransB = 111; // trans='N'
    int M = n1, N = n4, K = n2;
    int lda = K, ldb = N, ldc = N;
    ComplexDouble alpha = 1, beta = 0;
    ComplexDouble[,] c = new ComplexDouble[n1, n4];
    _mkl.cblas_zgemm(Order, TransA, TransB, M, N, K, alpha, a, lda, b, ldb, beta, c, ldc);
    return c;
}
```

And finally I've the following test code which runs fine under Windows but fails on Linux (Parameter 9 was incorrect on entry to cblas_zgemm).

```
ComplexDouble[,] A = new ComplexDouble[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
ComplexDouble[,] B = new ComplexDouble[,] { { 0, 1, 0, 1 }, { 1, 0, 0, 1 }, { 1, 0, 1, 0 } };
ComplexDouble[,] C = MKL.Dot(A, B);
```

I've made the following observations:

- It works on Windows
- It fails on Linux (Mono) with Parameter 9 was incorrect on entry to cblas_zgemm or Null Reference.
- If I repeat the experiment with `cblas_dgemm` and `double` it works on Windows and on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a closer look at `cblas_zgemm`

```
void cblas_zgemm (
    const CBLAS_LAYOUT Layout, const CBLAS_TRANSPOSE transa, const CBLAS_TRANSPOSE transb, const MKL_INT m, const MKL_INT n, const MKL_INT k, 
    const void *alpha, const void *a, const MKL_INT lda, const void *b, const MKL_INT ldb, 
    const void *beta, void *c, const MKL_INT ldc);
```

shows that the arguments `alpha` and `beta` must passed by reference. So the `DllImport`  must look like that:

```
[DllImport(DLLName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = false)]
internal static extern void cblas_zgemm(
    int Order, int TransA, int TransB, int M, int N, int K,
    ref ComplexDouble alpha, [In] ComplexDouble[,] A, int lda, [In] ComplexDouble[,] B, int ldb,
    ref ComplexDouble beta, [In, Out] ComplexDouble[,] C, int ldc);
```

I somehow missed that because for `cblas_dgemm`

```
void cblas_dgemm (
    const CBLAS_LAYOUT Layout, const CBLAS_TRANSPOSE transa, const CBLAS_TRANSPOSE transb, const MKL_INT m, const MKL_INT n, const MKL_INT k, 
    const double alpha, const double *a, const MKL_INT lda, const double *b, const MKL_INT ldb, 
    const double beta, double *c, const MKL_INT ldc);
```

the arguments `alpha` and `beta` are passed by value.

```
[DllImport(DLLName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = false)]
internal static extern void cblas_dgemm(
    int Order, int TransA, int TransB, int M, int N, int K,
    double alpha, [In] double[,] A, int lda, [In] double[,] B, int ldb,
    double beta, [In, Out] double[,] C, int ldc);
```

Like that `cblas_zgemm` works on Windows and on Linux. I still don't understand why it was working on Windows with the `ref`?